# Stamp out the Thalmor From Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been playing Skyrim with a few characters over the year since it has been out. I've always disliked the Thalmor and choose to eliminate them at every turn. So I've stormed their keep, burned down the embassy and killed any Justicars I find on the road. But, no matter what I still always find a few Justicars roaming the woods and roads from time to time.

Is there any way (without mods) to actually defeat and remove the Thalmor from Skyrim?

Now I don't run into them very often and they aren't hard to kill by any means, this is mainly an objective I'd personally like to accomplish.

Comment: The Thalmor are one of the [random encounters](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:World_Interactions#Encounters_With_Differing_Outcomes) in the game. That means that they will keep on respawning even if you kill all Thalmor that you encounter.

Comment: I my self have killed them all at the Thalmor Embassy but I still encounter some on the roads and haven't been able to eliminate them entirely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to completely remove them from Skyrim with out a mod (And I have actually not seen a mod that would do this but there are so many its possible I missed it).

The roaming bands of them are just a random encounter that always has the possibility of happening... and yes, I do attack them on site as well as they are ... well.. jerks is putting it lightly.

Comment: I did something to them at some point and now they attack *me* on sight, thus eliminating the small delay as I weigh how badly I want to kill them.